# I'm trying to define a button on tkinter, but i keep receiving an error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *


root = Tk()

# items frame
items = LabelFrame(root, text="items", padx=5, pady=5, bg="gray")
items.grid(row=0, column=0)

# items
cp = ["CRL", "+0,11%"]
cv = ["value:", "$33.68"]
cs = ["stock:", "0/85"]
cereals = LabelFrame(items, bg="gray", padx=5, pady=5)
cereals.grid(row=0, column=0)
tp1 = Label(cereals, text=cp, bg="gray", fg="white")
tp1.grid(row=0, column=1)
value1 = Label(cereals, text=cv, bg="gray", fg="white")
value1.grid(row=1, column=1)
stock1 = Label(cereals, text=cs, bg="gray", fg="white")
stock1.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

this button is giving me the error: graph1 = Button(cereals, text="test")
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

```
graph1 = Button(cereals, text="test")


root.mainloop()
```

I created another file. And made a simple button and it worked. So I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: you are setting `text` to a list? sounds fishy.

Comment: it's a place holder

Comment: This is one of the example which shows why not to use  `from x import *`.

Answer (score 1):

the line `graph1 = Button(cereals, text="test")` is using the `Button` attribute from the matplotlib.pyplot package not the tkinter package.

Do
`import matplotlib.pyplot as mp`

Instead of
`from matplotlib.pyplot import *`